# Sort a table based on a value present in a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table for testimonials, named 'testimonials_manager' and there is a column present named 'testimonials_image' for storing the testimonial image path and name.

I want to show my testimonial list and the list sort based on a image value that means the testimonial show first which contain image and those which not contain image it is showing in last.

Is it possible to sort the table based on a value present in a specific column? Please help me.

My table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testimonials_manager` (
  `testimonials_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `testimonials_title` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `testimonials_url` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `testimonials_name` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `testimonials_image` varchar(254) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `testimonials_html_text` text collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `testimonials_mail` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `testimonials_company` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `testimonials_city` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `testimonials_country` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `testimonials_show_email` char(1) collate utf8_unicode_ci default '0',
  `sidebox` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `testimonial_add` date NOT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime default NULL,
  `testimonial_products` varchar(300) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  `testimonial_categories` varchar(300) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`testimonials_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

Suppose, I have a 50 testimonial already inserted into my tables in which 30 testimonial has contain image and rest 20 testimonials has no image. I want to show first that 30 testimonials which contain image in my testimonial listing page and after that show those 20 testimonials which has no image.
I think you will understand what I am saying?

Comment: All you need is ORDER BY. Show us your table and some data and we can be more specific.

Comment: Please tell me where I post the MySQL table structure ?

Comment: You can edit your original post or even setup a [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Please see the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37243d , here is my table structure

Comment: You need to add some data to it so we can do some testing with you.

Comment: I add some data , please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f250e/2

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Please read my post again, I will edit a explanation at the bottom, I think now you will understand!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that :

```
SELECT  * FROM testimonials_manager ORDER BY testimonials_image
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why this is a good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM testimonials_manager
ORDER BY testimonials_image
```

In order to have the NULL testimonials_image values go to the bottom, but the rest of the results show in ascending order, you can replace the NULLs just in the order by clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM testimonials_manager
ORDER BY IFNULL(testimonials_image, 'zzz')
```

Comment: I checked your query but this is not what I want, It is not only sort the field, I want sort the image field which contain value at first

Comment: I checked your last query but it shows me the MySQL syntax error, will you please look at it and send me the right one

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your fiddle I ran this query -

```
SELECT *
FROM testimonials_manager
ORDER BY testimonials_image DESC
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc33d8/4)

You can also do this -

```
SELECT *
FROM testimonials_manager
ORDER BY ISNULL(testimonials_image), testimonials_image desc
```

Comment: No this is not fulfill my requirement, sorry , I already post my answer, I fixed my issue after trying a lot . Thanks again for spend some time and think about my problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I got my answer after trying a lot ... the query which fulfill my requirement is as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM `testimonials_manager` order by `testimonials_image` IS NULL DESC, `testimonials_image` DESC
```